# Incompatible Types in Blue J

Tags: java, bluej

I'm trying to create a class which answers the question below:

*Write a class to represent athlete records for an athletics club. An athlete record consists of a name, personal best (a floating point number) and discipline (e.g. sprinter, javelin, long jump etc). Once an athlete record has been created it should be possible to change the personal best and discipline but not the name.*

I'm getting the error incompatible types in the line:

**return personal();**

Why is this?

```
public class AthleteRecords{
private String name;
private int personal;
private String discipline;

public AthleteRecords(String n, int p, String d){
    name = n;
    personal = p;
    discipline = d;
}

public void setPersonal(int p){
    personal = p;
}

public void setDiscipline(String d){
    discipline = d;
}

public String getName(){
    return name;
}

public String getPersonal(){
    return personal;
}

public String getDiscipline(){
    return discipline;
}
}
```

Comment: The parameter `personal` is an `int`, but `getPersonal()` returns a `String`.

Comment: wow i'm so stupid. thanks for clearing that up.